# How to determine if a control is start initializing and complete initialized and binded

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-controls

I have a WinForms control with many different binded controls. The main control can be showed/hided several times with parent form. I would like to know when control starts initializing (first time or not), and when all bindings on its child controls is comlete.

If any have some ideas or way how to get this, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Shown or Load Event should help..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx

All possible events you find here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1s43eb

Comment: The problem is show events fires always when showing/hides control, and control have not Load event. Also I need to determinate whan all controls is complete binded. Any way thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with combination of events:

For transition to initialization state:

- initial state default in constructor
- ParentForm.FormClosed
- Control.ParentChanged

For transition to normal state (I need to transit to this state after all initial bindings complete and before user make some action):

- KeyDown
- MouseDown